# how to use media queries with javascript in my web parts - classic mode

Tags: css, branding

I have a site that is using the pnp responsive and the webparts are responsive.
But i'm using a jquery (easypaginate.js) in the webpart.

When i resize my webpart how can i dynamically change the step option to show only 3 li items when i resize the screen to let say 500px using (media queries) @media (max-width: 500px)

Below is the default setting options

```
$('ul#items').easyPaginate({
        step:7,
        nextprev:false,
        numeric:true
    }); 
}
```

I want the step to be 3 when i go on a smaller screen.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: i do not think you can apply any media query on this ,but for sure you can get the windows width and apply easypaginate plugin. if(window.width >500)$('ul#items').easyPaginate({
        step:7,
        nextprev:false,
        numeric:true
    }); 
}else{$('ul#items').easyPaginate({
        step:3,
        nextprev:false,
        numeric:true
    }); 
}}

Comment: Thanks .Will give it a short

Comment: Gave it a shot but didn't do it.It doesn't show the render the paginaton buttons. I think i need to pass some variable to the tepas depending on the window size for it to work

Comment: Any other solution for this scenario?